# Debian 10 connect to Wi-fi

Tags: debian, wifi, networkmanager, authentication

I'm conscious that this questions is quite basic but being honest I've being researching these days and I couldn't find how to do it.

I'm using Debian 10 Live and the only thing I really did was making it persistent.

It's been quite frustrating since all that is stopping me from using Debian as my main OS is the wireless connection, since I really like it and after that I wouldn't have to switch computers to make some research.

After what I've looked into I don't know if I have to install something, if so how to do it without internet in that computer, what to install or if it depends of my PC or the type of connection.

The network manager let me "create" a wireless connection which I don't know if means to actually create it or connect to an existing one, but after putting SSID and password it just said that I never connected to it.

I'm sorry as I feel this answer should be easy for me to find in the Internet but I honestly couldn't manage to do it. I really don't know like where to start.

Comment: https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/

Answer (score 0):

Most wireless cards these days require some sort of firmware.  Most of this firmware is not free software, so it isn't included in the main Debian archive.

If you're using Debian Live, you should try the unofficial version with non-free software, which is required for that non-free firmware.

If you're installing Debian, make sure you answer “yes” to the question about whether to use non-free software during the installation, or edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and change `main` to `main contrib non-free`.

Once you've done that, try to figure out which network card you have by running `lspci -v` and looking for the `Kernel driver in use` field for the card that looks like a wireless card (often, it will be labeled “Network controller”).  Run `apt-get update` and find the appropriate firmware package (try `apt search firmware wifi`) and install it, then reboot.  Things should just work after that.